# Using AWS Amplify, can I do 301 redirect from /**/index.html to /**/?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-amplify

Does AWS Amplify support dynamic matching syntax?

### It works:

```
[
    {
        "source": "/<*>/index.html",
        "target": "/<*>/",
        "status": "301",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

It can redirect /example/index.html to /example/, but /example/foobar/index.html is not redirected to /example/foobar/.

It seems that wildcard can't include any shashes.

### It doesn't work:

```
[
    {
        "source": "/^(.*)\\/index\\.html$/",
        "target": "/$1/",
        "status": "301",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

`()` cannot be reused by $1.

### My workaround:

[image]